# How to avoid implicit reference in .net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependencies

I have a project created in .netcore 3.1 and generated its project.dll file. In the project i am referencing some third party references like restSharp, BouncyCastle etc. if i reference this project.dll file in another project (my TestAPP) the above third party dependencies are automatically being downloaded in the package folder of the TestAPP and becoming available to use.

What i wanted is in the TestAPP i should have the option to manually include these dependencies.

i tried adding in my projects .csproj

```
<DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
```

but after adding it, it is somehow turning into .net standard project and throwing error like "add netstandard version 2.0.0.0" like that (i added that but the error was not going away)

is there any equivalent thing in .net core 3.1 ?
please help

Comment: So firstly, if the code isn't there it cant be run now matter how many levels of decencies you have. Secondly why is this a problem? Do you just want a single file application?

Comment: @TheGeneral we dont want to ship these dependencies with our dll, the client need to have an option to add them on their side.

Comment: This is a very very unusual requirement.... However, just send them, `yourAwesomeProject.dll` and nothing else or delete them in a post build event? However, this is bound to cause waaaaaay more issues than it solves.

Comment: I have the feeling you are using the wrong project template / type ...